# issue in merging json files in python

Tags: python, json, pandas, merge

I was trying to merge multiple json files with the same headers.
I used the the code discussed in other posts and tweaked a bit on destination folder as follow:

```
  import glob
  result= []
  filepath = 'D:/Football matters/Sttratagem data access/WYScout/trial data/MergeTest'
  all_header_files = glob.glob(filepath+'/*.json')

    for f in all_header_files:
        with open(f, "rb") as infile:
            result.append(json.load(infile))

    with open("merged_file.json", "wb") as outfile:
         json.dump(result, outfile)
```

When I loop it to merge, it showed some error as follow:

> `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`

You can download the sample file [Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1y8e9w6nMt5gRafznHWrzh0T7E1I1DJ95).

In my case, I have 100 over json files to merge into one.
Can anyone advise it how to merge?

Regards
Zep.

Comment: Are the json files in the current directory?

Comment: Hi Vikrant, All  files are in the same directory. Thanks

Comment: The posted answer should work.

Comment: Yeah. It worked in reading file. I have updated in the post that I have problem in merging the files. Would you please advise?

Comment: use `r` and `w` modes in the `open()` calls, instead of binary `rb` and `wb`

Comment: Thanks. I will try later.

Comment: Thanks Vikrant. It worked. Appreciate your advice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is in your usage of glob. Here's an example of its usage.

```
import glob
filepath = 'D:/Football matters/Sttratagem data access/WYScout/trialdata/MergeTest'
all_json_files = glob.glob(filepath+'/*.json')
```

You can now use a for loop as before with `all_json_files`

Comment: I updated it. It show empty value in all_header_files.

Comment: Can you update what changes you did in the question?

Comment: Hi Anand, Thanks for the reply and I have updated it.

Comment: Hi Andand I think beacuse of assigning a string separately in a variable. I directly insert the directory. it showed me file path including names

Comment: @Zephyr You have to merge the filepath variable. Check out the updated answer

Comment: It worked. When I loop it to merge. it has some error. I will update it in the question